# Loop runs 9 times and gains info gradually

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to pull in some data from my database, and the loop is behaving strangely. this is

my code:

```
<code>
  $query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%$search%'";

  $resultpage = "";

  $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

  $rows = array();

  $resultpage = "<table class='table table-striped table-hover><tbody><tr><td>Search Results</td></tr>";

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;

    foreach($rows as $row) {
      foreach($rows as $field => $value) {          
        array_unique($rows);
        $resultpage .= "<tr><td><a href='user?id=".$value["id"]."'>".$value["username"]."</a></tr></td>";
      }
    }      
  }
</code>
```

You can see what is output [here](http://dubstaphone.byethost3.com/search?q=r).

Basically, there are patterns of duplicate entries, and some of the entries don't even appear until you get farther down the list.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why do you array_unique($rows); inside loops where you iterate $rows?

Comment: Why do you iterate $rows nested?

Comment: @Anders Lindén I'm sorry, I'm still learning and I'm not sure what that means or how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean with strangely?

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt It's not very easy to explain, so I provided a link that demonstrates the issue

Comment: move `foreach($rows as $row)` outside of while statement

Comment: Is not both foreach loops removable? The while should do all looping, maybe I am wrong

Comment: i corrected your linking, but that still doesn't explain what you mean by "strange"...

Comment: @Deadooshka The variable $row doesn't exist outside of the while loop

Comment: @webeno Do you see how it has many duplicate entries, and some of the entries don't appear until the list gets longer?

Comment: see? you can explain it! :)

Comment: `$rows[] = $row;` it is in $rows array

Comment: @Deadooshka that is within the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am chancing a bit now:

```
<code>
  $query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%$search%'";

  $rs = mysqli_query($con,$query);

  echo "<table class='table table-striped table-hover'><tbody><tr><td>Search Results</td></tr>";

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {    
    $id = $row["id"];
    $username = html_encode($row["username"]);
    echo "<tr><td><a href='user.php?id=$id'>$username</a></td></tr>";
  }

  echo "</table>";
</code>
```

Comment: It works! The only thing is that the first result isn't styled in the table. what could be going on here?

Comment: Correcting the order of </td> and </tr>. They need to be closed in reverse order from <tr> and <td>

Comment: Notice that I trust $id to be an integer, so html_encode is never needed on it

Comment: Oh, hahah I had open quotes in the table tag. Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 1):

You need to end your while loop before you iterate through `$rows`. Let the while loop populate the array and then iterate through it. As it is right now, you're iterating through the `$rows` array while you are also populating it.

So what's happening here is:

Name 1 is found and added to array --> Array has 1 element. This element is printed.

Name 2 is found and added to array --> Array has 2 elements. Both elements are printed.

Etc. etc.

Here's the fix:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $rows[] = $row;
}

foreach($rows as $row) {
  foreach($row as $field => $value) {          
    array_unique($row);
    $resultpage .= "<tr><td><a href='user?id=".$value["id"]."'>".$value["username"]."</a></tr></td>";
  }
}
```

Comment: `foreach(*$row* as $field => ...`

Comment: Actually I don't really understand why there's a nested foreach.